# Reverse for 'PostDetail' not found. 'PostDetail' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django

I have two different views: one to render post and another one to render comments in those post. When I tried to redirect the post view from the comment view I am getting a error

```
> NoReverseMatch at /3/create Reverse for 'PostDetail' not found.
> 'PostDetail' is not a valid view function or pattern name. Request
> Method:   POST Request URL:   http://localhost:8000/3/create Django
> Version:  4.1.2 Exception Type:   NoReverseMatch Exception Value: 
> Reverse for 'PostDetail' not found. 'PostDetail' is not a valid view
> function or pattern name. Exception
> Location: /workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py,
> line 828, in _reverse_with_prefix Raised
> during:   website.views.createComment Python
> Executable:   /home/gitpod/.pyenv/versions/3.8.11/bin/python3 Python
> Version:  3.8.11 Python Path:  ['/workspace/RaizalDuo', 
> '/home/gitpod/.pyenv/versions/3.8.11/lib/python38.zip', 
> '/home/gitpod/.pyenv/versions/3.8.11/lib/python3.8', 
> '/home/gitpod/.pyenv/versions/3.8.11/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', 
> '/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages', 
> '/home/gitpod/.pyenv/versions/3.8.11/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
> Server time:  Sun, 12 Feb 2023 07:55:21 +0000 Traceback Switch to
> copy-and-paste view
> /workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py,
> line 55, in inner
>                 response = get_response(request) … Local vars /workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py,
> line 197, in _get_response
>                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) … Local vars /workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py,
> line 23, in _wrapped_view
>                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) … Local vars /workspace/RaizalDuo/website/views.py, line 51, in createComment
>             return redirect('PostDetail', newComment.post.id
```

I am trying to see the comment made in the post_details. html

Comment: please post urls.py and related view / template

Comment: url: from . import views
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings


urlpatterns = [
   
    path('', views.PostList.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('<int:post_id>', views.PostDetail, name='post_detail'),
    path('PostDetails', views.PostDetail, name='post_detail'),
    path('like/<int:id>/', views.PostLike, name='post_like'),  
    path("<int:post_id>/create", views.createComment, name="createComment"),
    path("comment/<int:comment_id>", views.updatecomment, name="updatecomment"),
]

Comment: change the redirect to redirect("post_detail" ....).

Answer (score 0):

url:

from . import views
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [

```
path('', views.PostList.as_view(), name='home'),
path('<int:post_id>', views.PostDetail, name='post_detail'),
path('PostDetails', views.PostDetail, name='post_detail'),
path('like/<int:id>/', views.PostLike, name='post_like'),  
path("<int:post_id>/create", views.createComment, name="createComment"),
path("comment/<int:comment_id>", views.updatecomment, name="updatecomment"),
```

]

Comment: I think, You got this error because you have two paths of same view.